# Is it possible in Interface Builder and Auto Layout to say "make this UILabel centered with the center of that other UILabel"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Is that only possible in code? Or can I do it in Interface Builder. If it's only possible in code, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select both labels, then add two Alignment Constraints: horizontal centres, and vertical centres.